# Configure laravel using mssql and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.5, laravel-query-builder

I am using laravel for an application which is using MySQL for all the data from/to web user interface.

My situation is: actually I have another application running exclusively with MSsql server.

> How could I run a SELECT query MSsql, get the data and then update a
>   MySQL table using a built in constructor?

Outside Laravel a try this and work perfectly:

```
<?php
$serverName = “MYPC/sqlexpress”;
$dataBase = “b2”;
$UID = “root”;
$PWD = “1234567890”;


Try {
$conn = new PDO(“sqlsrv:Server= $serverName;DataBase=$dataBase”, $UID, $PWD);

$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}

Catch(Exception $e)
{
die( print_r($e->getMessage() ) );
}

$Select = “SELECT * FROM AtdRecord”;

$t = sqlsrv_query(conn, $select);

While($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($t, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo $row[‘RecDate’];
}
```

Inside laravel, configured over .env file, For MySQL query’s I used the build in constructor

```
DB::
```

Just that easy

I am rookie in this. Hope I express my self correctly.

Comment: Please clearify: what exactly is your question?

Comment: laravel 5.4 or laravel 5.5?  laravel should support setting up multiple database connections at once define a name and use `DB::connection('name')...` to select the database connection you want.. Read ( https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database ) ( http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections ) ( https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/configuration-sql-server ) .. You need a combine the information on these links to a working solution.

Comment: @Namoshek done.